# What does the following entry in web.xml refer to?

Tags: jsp, tomcat, servlets, web.xml

one is under ROOT as webapps/ROOT/jsp/error.jsp and other is under webapps/documents/jsp/errorpage.jsp and my web.xml entry is as follows

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ErrorPage</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.jsp.jsp.error_jsp</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ErrorPage</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/jsp/errorpage.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

In general web.xml contains `servlet` and `servlet-mapping` entry. `servlet-mapping` entry contains the url and `servlet` entry contains the servlet path upto my understanding.

I couldn't understand the above entry in web.xml. Please help me know about it.

Comment: Have you considered consulting the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

From Servlet Specification:
*The servlet-class element contains the fully
 qualified class name of the servlet.*

You specify to the container (tomcat) that:
org.apache.jsp.jsp.error_jsp is the fully qualified class name of a Servlet called ErrorPage.

From Servlet Specification:
*The servlet-mappingType defines a mapping between a
 servlet and a url pattern.*

You specify to the container that requests with url /jsp/errorpage.jsp must be responded by server ErrorPage.

Example:

tomcat receives a first (i.e. first request to the servlet since app start) HTTP GET request having url /jsp/errorpage.jsp;

tomcat loads the class org.apache.jsp.jsp.error_jsp, creates an instance of the class, initializes the servlet and than calls the doGet() method of the servlet.